# Sort the values in the array in the recurring order provided by another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to sort randomly placed values in one `array` so that it matches the `order` provided by another array, but instead of appending the duplicates one after the other, the function should append the group of values, provided by the `order` variable, one after the other.

**Input:**

```
const array = [1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4];
const order = [5, 1, 3, 4];
```

**Correct Output:**

```
const correctlyOrderedArray = [5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5];
```

**Wrong Output:**

```
const wronglyOrderedArray = [5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4];
```

Comment: Its unclear what a *correct output* is.. Please give more samples

Comment: It is equally unclear what a *valid input* is..

Answer (score 0):

Two functions. The first one does the actual sorting and uses the second one inside itself.

**Primary function:**

```
function sortByOrder (array, order) {

    const arrayOfArrays = order.map(v => {

        return [...Array(howMany(v, array))].map(undef => v);
    });

    const tempArray = [];

    arrayOfArrays.forEach((subArr, i) => {

        let index = order.indexOf(order[i]);

        subArr.forEach(duplicate => {

            tempArray[index] = duplicate;

            index += order.length;
        });
    });

    return tempArray.filter(v => v);
}
```

**Subordinate function:**

```
function howMany(value, array) {

    const regExp = new RegExp(value, 'g');

    return (array.join(' ').match(regExp) || []).length;
}
```

Comment: You can consider adding this post to your question to explain what you tried

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that the array `order` contains all the non duplicated elements of the array `array`, one way to achieve the sorting could be to copy the element of order using a modulo so that, we can restart the copy from the beginning.

```js
const array = [1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4];
const order = [5, 1, 3, 4];

var newValue = []
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
newValue.push(order[i % order.length])
}

console.log(newValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could iterate over the order and shift out elements out of our array until its empty:

```
const array = [1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4];
const order = [5, 1, 3, 4];

let i = 0, exit = false;
const result = [];

while(array.length){
  const found = array.findIndex(el => el === order[i % order.length]);
  if(found+1){
    result.push( array.splice(found, 1)[0] );
    exit = false;
  }      
  if(i && i % order.length){
    if(exit){
      result.push(...array); //concat the rest
      break;
    }
    exit = true;
  }
  i++;
}
```

The exit boolean will terminate the program if one order iteration did not found anything, e.g.:

```
const order = [1,2,3], array = [4,5,6,1,2,3,1,2,3];
```

[Let it run!](http://jsbin.com/xocoyodeju/edit?console)